# OpenCV- Reading after n frames

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I have written the following code

```
import cv2
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd

cascPath = 'haarcascade_frontalface_dataset.xml'  # dataset
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('video1.mp4')

frames = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) 
fps = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)) 

print(frames) #1403 frames
print(fps) #30 fps
# calculate duration of the video 
seconds = int(frames / fps) 
print("duration in seconds:", seconds)  #46 seconds


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time(Seconds)', 'Status'])
start = time.time()
print(start)
n=5
while True:
    
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #converts frame to grayscale image
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                gray, scaleFactor=1.1,
                minNeighbors=5,
                minSize=(30, 30),
                flags=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        )
    if len(faces) == 0:
        print(time.time()-start, 'No Face Detected')
        df = df.append({'Time(Seconds)': (time.time()-start) , 'Status':'No Face detected' }, ignore_index=True)
    else: 
        print(time.time()-start, 'Face Detected')
        df = df.append({'Time(Seconds)':(time.time()-start), 'Status':'Face Detected' }, ignore_index=True)

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    df.to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            # print(df.head(2))
            break


# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you want to download the video I m working on, you can download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p9-aI_8cyPhqyKGo430E7EwqWgyW2E7E/view?usp=sharing)

download the haar cascade XML file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tjsr-2yPqR21XMEMxtMlZRLV2XIdMjSq/view?usp=sharing)

I have a few doubts in this.

1. Currently it is running on all the 1403 frames of the video, I want to optimize it such that it runs inference after every `n` frames, which is customizable. in code I have mentioned n =5. So, if n= 5. no of frames should be 1403/5 = 280
2. The timestamps in my CSV are not coming accurate, I want them to be relative to the video. Basically, the first column (Time(Seconds) should designate the time in the video and the status should determine the status (detected/not detected) of the frame at that moment, the Time(second) column should end at around 46 seconds which is the length of the video.
3. my cv2.imshow is showing a video that is somewhere around 2x speed, I believe I can control the speed by using cv2.imKey(), what should be the optimal parameter for cv2.waitKey so that I get a similar speed video as output.

Thanks for going through the whole question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read every 'n' frames, you can wrap your VideoCapture.read() call in a loop like this:

```py
for a in range(n):
    ret, frame = video_capture.read();
```

For the timestamps in the csv file, if that came with the dataset I'd trust that. It's possible the camera isn't capturing at a consistent framerate. If you think the framerate is consistent and want to generate the timestamps yourself you can keep track of how many frames you've gone through and divide the video length by that. (i.e. at frame 150 the timestamp would be (150 / 1403) * 46 seconds)

cv2.imshow() just shows frames as fast as the loop runs. This is mostly controlled through cv2.waitKey(milliseconds). If you think the processing that you're doing in the loop takes a negligible amount of time you can just set the time in the waitKey to be ((n / 1403) * 46 * 1000). Otherwise you should use the python time module to track how long the processing takes and subtract that time from the wait.

Edit:

Sorry, I should have been more clear with the first part. That for loop only has the VideoCapture.read() line in it, nothing else. This way you'll read 'n' frames, but only process one out of every 'n' frames. This isn't replacing the overall while loop that you already have. You're just using the for loop to dump the frames you want to skip.

Oh, and you should also have a check for the return value of the read().

```py
if not ret:
    break;
```

The program will probably crash at the end of the video if it doesn't have that check.

Comment: The for loop you mentioned will just capture only n frames, right. I mean, it will capture just n frames as the for loop is iterating over n vakues. So first iteration will be a= 1, second will be a=2, nth will be a= n